Double Trace of the tensor product of the metric tensor with vector fields.
So I am currently preparing for an exam on General Relativity and while reading the notes I stumbled upon this:
$$
tr[tr[g \otimes X \otimes Y]]= g(X,Y)
$$
Where
$$
g=g_{ij} dx^{i}\otimes dx^{j}
$$
is the metric tensor and
$$
X=X^{i}\partial_{i}\\
Y=Y^{i}\partial_{i}
$$
are vector fields. I know if $\omega$ is a $1-form$ and $v$ is an element of the tangent space we get
$$tr[\omega\otimes v]= \omega(v)=\omega_i v^i$$
but I fail to understand why
$$
tr[tr[g \otimes X \otimes Y]]= g(X,Y)
$$
I just started this semester studying differential geometry, so I may miss some of the intuition. Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Side comment: As @AndreasCap says, the notation used in this formula is ill-defined. I prefer the following notation: First, given a vector space $V$ and its dual $V^$, I write for each $\ell \in V^$ and $v \in V$, $$\langle\ell,v\rangle = \ell(v).$$ Then one can denote for each $\omega\in X^$, $\theta\in Y^$, $x \in X$, $y \in Y$, $$ \langle \omega\otimes\theta, x\otimes y\rangle = \langle\omega,x\rangle\langle\theta,y\rangle. $$ This extends uniquely to a function $$(X^\otimes Y^) \times (X\otimes Y) \mapsto \mathbb{R}. $$ Then $$ g(X,Y) = \langle g, X\otimes Y\rangle. $$

The notation you are using partly is not really well defined. There are (at least) two possible definitions of what $tr[g\otimes X\otimes Y]$ should mean, namely either $g(X,\ )\otimes Y$ or $g(\ ,Y)\otimes X$. (And the situation would be worse if the tensor field $g$ were not symmetric.) Here $g(X,\ )$ is the one-form obtained from plugging $X$ into $g$, so in components this is $g(X,\_)=g_{ij}X^idx^j$. Similarly $g(\ ,Y)=g_{ij}Y^jdx^i$. But using the formula for one-forms and vector fields you have, the trace of both $g(X,\ )\otimes Y$ and $g(\ ,Y)\otimes X$ is given by $g(X,Y)$ or in components by $g_{ij}X^iY^j$.
A correct notation would require indicating which of the two tangent components and which of the two cotangent components of $g\otimes X\otimes Y$ should be contracted. (As noted above, for the cotangent components this is irrelevant because of the symmetry of $g$.)

I should have been more clear with my notation. We have
$$
g \in T_{p}^{\star}M\bigotimes T_{p}^{\star}M
$$
and symmetric. Additionally we defined the trace of a tensor as
$$
tr[T_{i_1,…,i_k}^{j_1,…,j_l}]=T_{\alpha,i_2,…,i_k}^{\alpha,j_2,…,j_l}$$

So am I correct here:
$$
tr[tr[g\otimes X \otimes Y]]=tr[tr[g_{\alpha \beta} X^{\gamma} Y^{\delta} dx^{\alpha} \otimes  dx^{\beta} \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\gamma}} \otimes  \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\delta}}]]= tr[g_{\alpha \beta} X^{\alpha} Y^{\delta} dx^{\beta} \otimes  \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\delta}}]= g_{\alpha \beta} X^{\alpha} Y^{\beta} =g(X,Y)
$$

yes, this looks fine. Still, I would not call the operation you define "tr" since it is just convention that you contract the first upper and the first lower index.
